# Angular : Save editable PDF data using angular/javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pdf-viewer

Html:

```
  <iframe [src] ="fileurl" #iframe>
     </iframe>
     <button (click)="saveDoc()">
     </button>
```

Stuck at savedoc() functionality.

Typescript:

```
    /*api call to get document blob data on load*/
     var fileurl = new blob([res.body],{type:application/pdf});
     fileurl = URL.createObjectUrl(fileurl);

    savedoc(){//here need logic to access edited pdf content as blob }
```

I am able to view and write in pdf editable fields (as input or checkboxes) but I can't figure out once filled all details, how to save/access that edited PDF content (mostly in blob format) to send back to server when click on save button. I have also tried ng2-pdf-viewer library of npm but same issue. I have to send this edited pdf to server in blob format to replace with existing.

How can I access edited pdf content?

Edited: Alternative approach, if its possible to trigger saveAs event from code to save iFrame pdf in local drive? I am using  Window.showSaveFilePicker();but saved file seem corrupted or not exist.

Comment: Actually its something that if user open a pdf and edit in that, when he/she saves it, edited pdf should be replaced with existing. so all i need is that on save button click , access processed/modified pdf. whenever i try to console iframe native element document, i see original PDF not edited one.

Answer (score 1):

###### Have a look at [PDF-LIB](https://pdf-lib.js.org/).

It is a great JavaScript library which provides all sorts of tools to manipulate PDF documents. There is even tooling for filling the fields and saving the newly filled PDF.

In a past project, I used this library to capture user information from an HTML form and have it inserted and saved into a PDF.

*Note:
Remember that once you have the filled PDF on client side, you must send it back to server side to update the PDF that is stored on the server.*